# How to pass a variable and json to a webservice.

Tags: java, web-services

I have 2 web services -

```
1) http://address.to.web.service/product/getProductById?productId=1000
2) http://address.to.web.service/product/updateProduct
```

The first one gets the product while the other one updates it.

the updateService takes input as a json  -

```
{
  "productId" : 1,
  "productName" : "XYZ",
  "Price": "$25.00"
}
```

I tested both the urls using Postman and works fine.

Being new to web service, 
I want to know what is the best way to pass a parameter to the webservice.

Is passing JSON similar to passing an integer value?

Answer (score 1):

For calling a web service from Java, try the [RestTemplate](https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate) from Spring, described in their step by step tutorial.

Comment: Where can i get some help with this? Can you please share any online reading material? what exctly shud i even search?

Comment: you mean how to do the PUT from java? see the spring framework and the RestTemplate client side utility, in this step by step guide https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate

Comment: As of now, I am not using any framework for development.. Its just calling the webservice to get the data. Is this doable?

Comment: I already tested using Postman... now when i need to implement this through code in Java.. I was expecting it to be simple enough... to just spill the beans, maybe like create a WebService Client object, add a parameter (for eg. productId) and then execute the url. In case of update, create aJSON object and add it to the WebService Client object and execute the url. Am I simplifying this a lot? Is it more complex than that?

Comment: I think your best bet to call it from Java is the Spring RestTemplate and their tutorial, I reposted the link. They design the tutorials to be full step by step guides to be done in less than 1 hour. There is no class to be used from the JDK to directly do this in a simple way, your best bet is to use a library. I propose this one because you would find the largest amount of tutorials and help online for it

Comment: Got it! I'm gonna try it right now. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

So far, I cannot tell you how to archive that using java, but you can try using curl:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"productId" : 1,  "productName" : "XYZ", "Price": "$25.00"}' http://address.to.web.service/product/updateProduct
```

As you can see, you have to specify you are going to send `json` content and also the HTTP method (POST to create resources).

PS. Try PATCH to update.

**edit**

I've done that, first you need to import the required classes:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
```

with this method:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://address.to.web.service/product/updateProduct");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    out.writeBytes("{\"productId\" : 1,  \"productName\" : \"XYZ\", \"Price\": \"$25.00\"}");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: OH! so whatever you write in DataOutputStream is effectively the input to the webservice. Is that correct?

Comment: It is only scapping the double quotes with backslashes. As you can see, it is not necessary with curl (unless you are on Windows) but in java it is.

Comment: I see... In this case, if I have to pass just one value, like productId, I need to change the RequestProperty too? is that correct?